# How to get SiriKit selection event for INTask?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirikit

I am developing an application with `Sirikit`. Using Sirikit, I have Shown a list of items as `INTask` and when I select any item from the list the original app will open, I have achieved till this.

My actual requirement is: I need to identify which item the user has selected from the Sirikit and I need to open different `ViewControllers` for different items. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.
Any help appreciated.